# Make matrix convolution in python faster

Tags: python, numpy, convolution

I am doing the matrix convolution. Here is my "hand-made" code. But it is VERY slow. I want to make it work as fast as the same code in C. There is a function "numpy.convolve()" that can make it much faster as I know but I don't get how to apply it to my code. Any ideas?

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab


def convolution(x):
    mysum = 0
    for i in xrange(0,20):
        mysum += mlab.normpdf(int(x) - 10+i,x,5)*frame[i+int(x)-10+100]

    return mysum

def main():

    global frame

    while(1):

        res   = []
        light = []
        frame = []

        for i in range(0,200,1):
            temp = (mlab.normpdf(i-100,10,5)+0.05*random.random())
            frame.append(temp)

        imax = 0
        rmax = 0


        for i in range(0,1800,1):
            r = convolution((i-900)/10)
            if rmax<r:
                rmax = r
                imax = i/10



        print(imax / 10.0)

main()
```

Comment: Anastasia, it might help us if you were to say what your code is meant to do, in English. Is it possible that https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html does what you need?

Comment: @BillBell Okey, look. Array "frame" - it is array of 200 doubles, that are organized with the normal distribution law. Further comes the matrix convolution BUT for the each element computations should be done 10 times with using Gaussian function. Standard function convolve() doesn't have such a feature.

Comment: There is a `while` loop that goes forever (no `break` or `return`). Is this the complete code you're working with?